# What exactly happens inside extended euclidean algorithm's recursion in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, recursion, number-theory

I know what extended euclidean algorithm is and why it is used in programming. It is a very useful algorithm for finding inverse modulo of a number. I know how to implement it in c++ and this is how I implement it below in c++.

```
typedef pair<int, int> pii;

#define x first
#define y second

pii extendedEuclidean(int a, int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        return {a,0};
    else {
        pii d = extendedEuclidean(b, a%b);
        return {d.y, d.x - (d.y*(a/b))};
    }
}
```

Now if I want to find the inverse modulo of a number for example 13 where mod is for example 1000007, then I simply call this function by

```
pair<int, int> res = extendedEuclidean(13, 1000007);
```

Then the result is

```
res.first
```

My question is why and what exactly happens inside this recursion? And also why it produce correct result.

N.B: here gcd(a, b) must be 1.

Comment: It does exactly what the code says. :/.

Comment: Don't you understand the algorithm or why g the code that you wrote implements that algorithm?

Comment: Wehn you write “I know how to implement it in c++”, does that mean that you implemented this yourself, or just that you know a code snipped which does it? In the former case, you should provide some info about the second element of the result. Otherwise you should name your source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Euclidean algorithm calculates the greatest common divisor of a pair of numbers `(a, b)` (assuming that `a>b`). It uses the observation that any common divisor of `a` and `b` is also a divisor of `a-b`. Here is why:

Let `d` be the divisor. Then, `a` can be expressed as `a=d*k` for an integer `k` and `b=d*l` for an integer `l`. Then, `a-b=d*k-d*l=d*(k-l)`. `k-l` is again an integer. Thus, `d` must be a divisor of `a-b`.

What the algorithm does is subtracting the smaller number from the bigger one as often as possible. This is the part `a%b`. E.g. if `a = 25` and `b = 7`, `a%b=4` is what you get after subtracting `b` 3 times from `a`. After that, the new `a` will be smaller than `b`. Therefore, you swap both numbers. This is the part where you call the recursion: `extendedEuclidean(b, a%b);`

The extended Euclidean algorithm does a bit more. Additionally, it calculates two numbers `x` and `y`, such that `gcd(a, b) = x * a + y * b`. Here is how it's done:

In the last iteration, you end up with `a'=gcd` and `b'=0`. Thus, you have `gcd=a' * 1 + b' * 0`, where `1` and `0` are `x'` and `y'`, respectively. Assume that the values in the previous iteration were `a''` and `b''`. Then we know that `a'=b''` and `b'=a'' % b''`. With this, we find that `b'=a''-(a''/b'')*b''` (subtract as often as possible). And we can modify

```
gcd = a' * x' + b' * y'
gcd = b'' * x' + (a''-(a''/b'')*b'') * y'
    = a'' * y' + b'' * (x' - y' * (a''/b''))
```

Hence, the new `x''=y'` and `y''=x' - y' * (a''/b'')`. This is your return statement `return {d.y, d.x - (d.y*(a/b))};`.

An example:

Let `a=25, b=7`. The first pass calculates the columns `a` and `b` (top to bottom). This accounts for the recursive calls. The second pass calculates the columns `x` and `y` (bottom to top). This accounts for the return statements:

```
 a  | b            |  x   | y                     | means
----+--------------+------------------------------+---------------------
 25 |  7           |  2   | -1 - 2 * (25/7) = -7  | 1 = 2 * 25 - 7 * 7 
  7 |  25 % 7 = 4  | -1   |  1 + 1 * (7/4)  =  2  | 1 = (-1) * 7 + 2 * 4
  4 |  7 % 4  = 3  |  1   |  0 - 1 * (4/3)  = -1  | 1 = 1 * 3 - 1 * 3
  3 |  4 % 3  = 1  |  0   |  1 - 0 * (3/1)  =  1  | 1 = 0 * 3 + 1 * 1
  1 |  3 % 1  = 0  |  1   |  0                    | 1 = 1 * 1 + 0 * 0
```

So you get `1 = 2 * 25 - 7 * 7` where `2` is the result's `.first` and `-7` is the result's `.second`. If we are in `mod 25`, this reduces to:

```
1 == 2 * 0 - 7 * 7
1 == -7 * 7
```

Hence, `-7 == 18` (which is `result.second`) is the multiplicative inverse of `7 (mod 25)`. Note that I swapped the input to avoid an unnecessary first iteration. Otherwise, it is `result.first`.